# Writing to Excel using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 + Editing at the same time

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

I used the code described [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-update.htm) to update an excel sheet using c#.
The problem is that the file gets locked and cannot be edited manually while it is being updated (unlike the example code, i am doing constant updates, realtime data feed)
Since it is a trading application, operators need to be able to add excel formulas while other cells are being updated.

I am new to this and open to switch to any other technology/architecture making this possible.
I am receiving a data feed and I just want to put in an excel file and update it in realtime while making it possible for sheets to be edited manually. 
I guess if the dll or add-in is called from within excel rather than oledb I would not have such a lock issue. So if there is any way to call my code from excel and not the other way round (not too painstaking if possible) I welcome any suggestion

**EDIT : Solution** 
*I finally opted for RTD Technology for Excel which is exactly what I was looking for.

MS Reference is 10 years old and VBA oriented but it gives the big guidelines and things did not change much since. I think I would not have made it through without [Kenny Kerr's Artcile on the subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/11/13/Rtd3.aspx). 
Many thanks to him.*

Comment: Excel is no a database. You're not going to get two pieces of code writing to the same file at the same time.

Comment: @Saunders : That's not the case. There is only one piece of code here which is the datafeed. Plus, I already saw applications do this in my previous company. But I have no idea what was behind it.

Comment: I don't believe you did. There's no way to update an Excel file in-place.

Comment: @JohnSaunders your are right, updating the Excel from two different processes in parallel won't work... BUT with an Excel RTD (which is an interface for exactly the scenario the OP describes) it is possible because that works from inside Excel...

Comment: @Yahia : Hello Again :-) Yeah I saw stuff about RTD but there was not much resources (I saw Kenny Kerr's minimal's implementation) I welcome any good track on that

Comment: @MikaJacobi Hello again :-) see my answer below... the links should get you started on RTD... I included even links to libraries which make the development rather easy :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to integrate into Excel itself... Excel offers an interface to achieve exactly what you describe... it is based on COM and called RTD (Realtime Data-Server) and gets called from Excel.

You have to build a COM component which adheres to the official spec...

Some usfeul links to get you started:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140059%28v=office.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.rtd%28v=office.11%29.aspx
- http://exceldna.codeplex.com/workitem/5902 (free library to ease the development)
- http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-excel-rtd-servers.php (commercial library to ease the development)

Comment: Thank you, Yahia. You helped me again. I did not want to jump into RTD wihtout having any feedback about it. I'll dig your links and prepare to get deeper into it. PS : I saw add-in-express article before and when I saw the purchase button and I ran away :-)  Are you sure the library is free ? I Looked here http://www.add-in-express.com/downloads/index.php

Comment: @MikaJacobi the third link (exceldna) is a free library, the fourth link (add-in-express) is commercial...

Comment: @MikaJacobi IF this is a commercial app (you wrote a trading app) I would strongly recommend using the add-in-express option since you get solid support...

Comment: I have to deliver a free prototype first and if customer is satisfied i'll go commercial. That's why I need free/open source for a starter.

Comment: The Excel-DNA support for RTD servers is nice because it works without requiring installation or registration, and works without requiring admin rights on the client. There are some simple sample RTD sources in the distribution.